# Could we have an auto generated short URL for questions on the sites?

Tags: feature-request, domain-names

Idea taken from doctype.com

When a question is asked an auto generated short URL (perhaps using a special "short domain" purchased for just this purpose) provided for use in twitter, or if passing along in SMS format.

---

On 10/19/2011 a blog post on Stackexchange.com for podcast #23 provided notice that StackExchange.com has the amazingly short URL [s.tk](http://s.tk) so it would seem that the StackExchange.com sees value in having a "short URL", using s.tk as the domain you could access a question on stackexchange.com such as [s.tk/joel](http://s.tk/joel) to access Joel Spolsky's user page on StackExchange.com

It would seem that the top sites (such as StackOverflow.com, SuperUser.com, ServerFault.com, etc.) would also benefit from a short URL as well as an "auto generated" short URL for questions on top SE sites.

Comment: While I know that there are plenty of easy ways to get a short URL for twitter I was thinking more about SMS format for texting; however I expected to get more of a response if I mentioned twitter.

Comment: Try removing the title and abbreviating `questions` to `q`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21361 Should be short enough for anyone.

Answer (score 18):

A brand-new SO question URL is at minimum 43 characters today. That's cutting off the title, leaving only the protocol, domain, and path through the question ID.

That leaves you a whopping ***97 characters*** in which to **Tweet your Twitter** (or whatever you kids are calling it now). You might think that's not enough characters to write anything useful with, but frankly, neither is 140 characters and you accepted *that* limitation when you signed on. So, suck it up. If you finally do realize that you don't have room for everything you want to write, then **write a blog entry somewhere**, include in it the link to the SO question in all of its glory, complete with a proper title and perhaps a title tip listing the author and then *link to that* in your **Twitter Tweet**.

Comment: While true in 2009, [nowadays](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23834/official-shortened-url-service/75352#75352) [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4727477](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4727477) works too, being 34 characters for SO. That's 9 more to type, an increase of almost 10%!

Comment: @Arjan: And that's *just* enough room to write "ROTFLMAO!"

Answer (score 5):

For most twitter apps, it's literally one click to generate the shortened url...is that really too tasking? :)

Answer (score 3):

Register a domain, have Apache run on it (I'm sure IIS is able to do that too somehow), and redirect everything you get to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/$1

Or do that in an iframe and put lots of blinky ads around it. Soon, you're going to be rich.

Comment: SO busts out of iframes :)

Comment: Then a frame-buster-buster is needed.

Comment: Actually if you get credit for views, all you would have to do is delay loading the IFrame (using Javascript) until after the ads have loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of a custom shortened domain, like Wordpress has wp.me. There's probably some worthy 2-character domain name that's catchy (and most importantly available). I'm such a nice guy that I **didn't** just register a very obvious one.