# Deleted answers still appear in inbox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, global-inbox, information-display

Deleted answers appear in the global inbox. The same way it used to happen 
[with comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox)

Also the number of answers takes the deleted ones into account.

Comment: It's caused by caching. Actually, I find this behaviour rather handy for returning to deleted questions.

Comment: @Pekka It definitely still gives me the wrong amount of answers after refreshing. It might get handy if I ever get enough rep to see deleted answers and questions but for now...

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the Inbox links for new *comments* to (deleted) answers odd as well?

Like today I got the following link for a notification of a new comment *on an answer*:

> [/questions/750**95**/...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/why-do-the-so-e-mail-notifications-take-so-long-to-arrive)

<s>This gets me a `404 Not Found` as</s> Meanwhile that answer is deleted. But the question to which that deleted answer was posted has id `75056`. So, despite the `/questions` prefix, the `75095` above refers to the id of the deleted *answer*, and I would expect the link to be:

> [/questions/750**56**/.../75095#75095](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75056/why-do-the-so-e-mail-notifications-take-so-long-to-arrive/75095#75095)

But: <s>when the answer is not deleted (or for those who can see deleted posts)</s> the first actually redirects to the latter, using a `302 Found` response. So I assume these URLs are `status-bydesign`?

(For new *answers*, the URL in the Inbox is always a proper URL of the second form.)

Comment: The link target is indeed a deleted answer.

Comment: Oddly enough the link to your comment, @Jon, in my Inbox, is indeed pointing to this very answer, in [a "question-like" URL using an answer id](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/deleted-answers-still-appear-in-inbox), which then does a `302 Found` rewrite for a proper URL. HOWEVER: other links in that same Inbox use [an answer-like URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/is-imgur-losing-images/75108#75108). The latter would still work when that answer is gone. Hmmm, why two different types of URLs in the Inbox then?

Comment: Maybe it's because my comment is on one of your own answers? Those you can always see. Though I'm not sure why the /questions/75095 does a 404 -- I would have thought it would redirect just like the other link.

Comment: Aha, smart thinking, @Jon. So, I guess there is some bug here, but I am not sure if the question-like URL based on an answer id should work, or that such URLs should simply not be used in the Inbox.

Comment: Ah, the answer-like URLs refer to new answers, while the question-like URLs (using answer ids) are used for new comments, in that Inbox.

Comment: I dunno. It's a tough situation given that the inbox item stays put. Either the user gets a 404, or they get directed to a page where the reply doesn't even exist, where they might be looking around for it. Now that I think about it, given those two choices, it's probably less confusing with a 404, even though that doesn't *really* make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been caused by some transient network issues earlier today.

There haven't been any changes around the inbox in quite a while.

Comment: I doubt it was earlier today, considering it was reported two months ago. Perhaps it was fixed without being marked status-completed or not fixed at all? (I don't have a test case, but I'm sure you guys do).