# Why do the SO e-mail notifications take so long to arrive?

Tags: discussion, email

I'm guessing the answer may be too many so users and not enough up scaling because scaling up costs cash for hardware and other infrastructure.

Performance example:  my last two notifications of answers arrived long after I had discovered the answers on the so and meta sites.

Counter example:  notifications from forums.asp.net usually arrive in a timely fashion; however, Microsoft funds forums.asp.net and it's rumoured that Jeff Atwood is not as wealthy as the company affectionately known as "the evil empire" (although AFAIK Jeff has had three monitors since 2006 or before).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notification system doesn't send E-Mail instantly upon arrival of a new answer, but  daily.

> notify me **daily** of any new answers

The official reason for this can be found in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600).

Comment: Hi Pekka, at the *official reason* that you quoted above, Jeff wrote in part *"Email is for the less urgent stuff where you're busy and don't have time to check the site."* but *for me*, this is not the case because I frequently visit my e-mail inbox to check for updates from many sources such as customers, product support specialists, forums.asp.net, et cetera.

Comment: @gerry that's a fair argument, but I'm just a user so I have no influence on how this is done... You can add your arguments to the other question, but I have the feeling the team's mind is fairly set on the issue so it's unlikely this will change. There are third-party RSS-to-e-mail-services that might help you with this, though.