# Please implement notifications on an as-it-happens basis

Tags: discussion, status-completed, notifications

My temporary blindness as pointed out in a comment by Pekka:
*[Why do the SO e-mail notifications take so long to arrive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75056/why-do-the-so-e-mail-notifications-take-so-long-to-arrive)*

Scenario: x makes a post. x might edit her/his post.  For that reason as delay of 15 minutes following an edit would be a reasonable delay IMHO.

Personally, I'd like such notices; daily for me is not frequent enough.

Answer (score 3):

This already exists, for answers to your questions and responses to you. See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff, your answer is **not** the answer to my question. OTOH, I'm very glad that you pointed this out to me ... it's very useful.  *The reason that it does **not** answer my question* is because it requires the developer to visit the site to check status.  OTOH, receiving an e-mail in my inbox would at least for me be substantially more useful.  imho, this would make the utiltiy of your excellent sites even more excellent.  regards/g.

Comment: @gerry then perhaps you want tag set email notifications? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/

Comment: the email notifications look interesting especially if one wanted to follow someting like xUnit.net or MVC 3. However, for specific threads, the tag set technique would be overkill imho.  your recent suggestion in another thread to explore the so API is also interesting ... unfortunately I do not have time to explore it in the immediate future (if I do and can create something that does work, I'll be happy to share it because I'm not the only so community member who is looking for this type of solution). thnx

Comment: @gerry that site has applications pre-built by others, not just API information. Try reading a little more closely.