# How do I get an email every time sombody responds to one of my questions on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, email, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why do the SO e-mail notifications take so long to arrive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75056/why-do-the-so-e-mail-notifications-take-so-long-to-arrive)
>   [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

I signed up yesterday for stackoverflow.com and asked my first question, and now more than 24hours later I get my first email with a bunch of responses... how come it took so long to let me know I had answers? I would like to get an email immediately for every response... how do I do that?

Thanks