# Receive email immediately on answer?

Tags: support, answers, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get an email every time sombody responds to one of my questions on stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75181/how-do-i-get-an-email-every-time-sombody-responds-to-one-of-my-questions-on-stack)

Is it possible to receive an email immediately after one of my questions is answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can select to receive emails daily by checkmarking the box at the bottom of your questions, but there is no option for immediate emails. However, if you stay on a Stack Exchange site, the inbox in the upper left hand corner of every page will alert you to any new replies within seconds. You can also use the RSS feed on any questions (bottom right of the question page) to pipe new responses into a RSS reader.

Comment: I think the RSS feed might be the way to go. Basically I want something on my computer to 'beep' to tell me my question has been answered. I just assumed email was the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: There's also notification apps on http://stackapps.com/ you could use, although RSS is probably simplest