# Are there any URL shorteners for Stack Overflow and/or Stack Exchange in general?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, short-links, vanity-url

Site-specific URL shorteners would be so handy, especially when I'm writing tweets:

Instead of:

> [Wiki software for documenting APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331134/wiki-software-for-documenting-apis)

Or:

> http://bit.ly/e2oLNN

I could post:

> [stackoverfl.ow/e2oLNN](http://stackoverfl.ow/e2oLNN)

Has anyone implemented this yet? If not, I might register one myself and get started.

Comment: Actually, seems this has been requested before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23834/official-shortened-url-service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

Note that the word "link" under every the question contains the short URL you are looking for.

[image]

Also, for unanswered *zero answer* questions we now show this text at the bottom of the question:

> #### Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, twitter, or facebook.

The word "link" is the short attributed form:

`http://stackoverflow.com/q/4331625/1234`

Assuming you are logged in, you can delete the last `/1234` which is your user ID.

`http://stackoverflow.com/q/4331625`

Comment: When I press the link flag for this answer, I get  "http://" + "meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/71313/are-there-any-url-shorteners-for-stack-overflow-and-or-stack-exchange-in-general/71320#71320". Is it only for some sites? I've been using it for a while on SO and only get long urls there as well.

Comment: @aaron this is for *questions* and not *answers* but see Jon's answer.

Comment: ah yes. That's clear to me now. That's a handy feature for duplicates. I've just been triple clicking the url bar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, built in, although not documented well (probably best documented here on Meta).

[Wiki software for documenting APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331134)

The syntax to link directly to an answer is the same as above, except you use the answer identifier instead of the question identifier. I.e., to link to this answer is https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71314

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea;

http://so.com/q/4331625 for questions [q for question]

http://so.com/a/4331626 for answers [a for answer]