# What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?

Tags: support, faq, hyperlinks, s.tk, short-links

It was announced on [the Stack Exchange Podcast episode #23](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-23/) (at 1:05:26) that Stack Exchange has its own URL shortener, `http://s.tk/`.

Users can't create their own, they can only use the ones that are built-in.

What shortened URLs are available through it?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is a community-maintained list of publicly-known s.tk URLs. Please note that several links have broken or been removed in the past. Long-term stability is not guaranteed.

Note: The SE team [announced on October 6, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301751) that no more s.tk URLs will be created.

#### General

- [`/`](http://s.tk/):
  [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)
- [`/about`](http://s.tk/about):
  [About Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about)
- [`/androidannouncement`](http://s.tk/androidannouncement): [Stack Exchange for Android is here! – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/27/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/?utm_source=google-plus&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=android-app-launch&utm_content=android-app-launch-blog-post-google-plus)
- [`/apps`](http://s.tk/apps):
  [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)
- [`/area51`](http://s.tk/area51)
  [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/attribution`](http://s.tk/attribution):
  [Stack Exchange Attribution Policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)
- [`/blog`](http://s.tk/blog):
  [Stack Overflow Company Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`/careers`](http://s.tk/careers):
  [Stack Overflow Careers for employers](https://business.stackoverflow.com/careers)
- [`/chat`](http://s.tk/chat):
  [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/data`](http://s.tk/data):
  [Stack Exchange Data Explorer aka SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com)
- [`/employer`](http://s.tk/employer): [Product Guidance | Stack Overflow Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/guides)
- [`/faq`](http://s.tk/faq):
  [Stack Exchange Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)
- [`/jeff`](http://s.tk/jeff):
  [Jeff Atwood's Stack Exchange Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1)
- [`/jobs`](http://s.tk/jobs):
  [Stack Exchange Open Positions](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here)
- [`/joel`](http://s.tk/joel):
  [Joel Spolsky's Stack Exchange Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4)
- <s>[`/linkrequest`](http://s.tk/linkrequest):
  [s.tk Short URL Request Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHZLQjdhWjdyRGRub21TTjNMOXo2Mnc6MQ&ndplr=1)</s> (Note: As of October 6, 2017, [no new s.tk URLs are being created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301751).)
- [`/livechat`](http://s.tk/livechat):
  [Live Podcast Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/512/se-podcast-live-chat)
- [`/livestream`](http://s.tk/livestream): [Stack Exchange - live streaming video powered by Livestream](http://original.livestream.com/stackexchange)
- [`/newsletters`](http://s.tk/newsletters):
  [Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters)
- [`/NYCTour`](http://s.tk/NYCTour): Google street view tour of the NYC office - Stack Exchange
- [`/onhold`](http://s.tk/onhold)
  [Before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question)
- [`/podcastrss`](http://s.tk/podcastrss)
  [Podcast RSS Feed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/)
- [`/sites`](http://s.tk/sites)
  [Stack Exchange Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)
- [`/story`](http://s.tk/story)
  [Stack Overflow Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join)
- [`/team`](http://s.tk/team):
  [Stack Exchange Team Listing](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team)
- [`/workhere`](http://s.tk/workhere):
  [Stack Exchange Candidate Brochure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcrZPPFlhNTNE8xMDA2TWFjM0k/edit?usp=sharing)

#### Communities

- [`/android`](http://s.tk/android):
  [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/apple`](http://s.tk/apple):
  [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/bikes`](http://s.tk/bikes):
  [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/christianity`](http://s.tk/christianity):
  [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/crypto`](http://s.tk/crypto):
  [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/cstheory`](http://s.tk/cstheory):
  [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/cooking`](http://s.tk/cooking):
  [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/dba`](http://s.tk/dba):
  [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/design`](http://s.tk/design):
  [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/dsp`](http://s.tk/dsp):
  [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/diy`](http://s.tk/diy):
  [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/drupal`](http://s.tk/drupal):
  [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/ee`](http://s.tk/ee):
  [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/gamedev`](http://s.tk/gamedev):
  [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/gis`](http://s.tk/gis):
  [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/golf`](http://s.tk/golf):
  [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/japanese`](http://s.tk/japanese):
  [Japanese Language and Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/judaism`](http://s.tk/judaism):
  [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/miyodeya`](http://s.tk/miyodeya):
  [Mi Yodeya Publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications)
- [`/meta`](http://s.tk/meta):
  [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/money`](http://s.tk/money):
  [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/movies`](http://s.tk/movies):
  [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/musicians`](http://s.tk/musicians):
  [Musical Practice and Performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/parenting`](http://s.tk/parenting):
  [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/patents`](http://s.tk/patents):
  [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/photo`](http://s.tk/photo):
  [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/physics`](http://s.tk/physics):
  [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/ptso`](http://s.tk/ptso):
  [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`/review`](http://s.tk/review):
  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/rpg`](http://s.tk/rpg)
  [Role Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/scifi`](http://s.tk/scifi):
  [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/security`](http://s.tk/security):
  [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/sharepoint`](http://s.tk/sharepoint):
  [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/skeptics`](http://s.tk/skeptics):
  [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/soes`](http://s.tk/soes):
  [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`/stats`](http://s.tk/stats):
  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/tex`](http://s.tk/tex):
  [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/travel`](http://s.tk/travel):
  [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/unix`](http://s.tk/unix):
  [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/ux`](http://s.tk/ux):
  [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/webapps`](http://s.tk/webapps):
  [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/webmasters`](http://s.tk/webmasters):
  [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/wp`](http://s.tk/wp):
  [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

#### Beta Communities

- [`/astronomy`](http://s.tk/astronomy):
  [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/avp`](http://s.tk/avp):
  [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/beer`](http://s.tk/beer):
  [Homebrewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/bitcoin`](http://s.tk/bitcoin):
  [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/bricks`](http://s.tk/bricks):
  [Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/cars`](http://s.tk/cars):
  [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/fitness`](http://s.tk/fitness):
  [Fitness and Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/french`](http://s.tk/french):
  [French Language and Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/gardening`](http://s.tk/gardening):
  [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/german`](http://s.tk/german):
  [German Language and Usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/hermeneutics`](http://s.tk/hermeneutics):
  [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/history`](http://s.tk/history):
  [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/linguistics`](http://s.tk/linguistics):
  [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/philosophy`](http://s.tk/philosophy):
  [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/pm`](http://s.tk/pm):
  [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/productivity`](http://s.tk/productivity):
  [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/quant`](http://s.tk/quant):
  [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/scicomp`](http://s.tk/scicomp):
  [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/sqa`](http://s.tk/sqa):
  [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)
- [`/writers`](http://s.tk/writers):
  [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)

#### Easter Eggs

> - [`/hyphen`](http://s.tk/hyphen): **The hyphen site**
> - [`/stk`](http://s.tk/stk): **See [`/stk`](http://s.tk/stk)**
> - [`/unicorn`](http://s.tk/unicorn): **Candy Mountain**
> - [`/StackOverflowSecrets`](http://s.tk/StackOverflowSecrets): **Direct access to secret keys**

Comment: Is this list still up-to-date?

Comment: Links are added as they are discovered. So there's a possibility that there exists sites that have links but are not listed. If you find any, feel free to add to the list.

Comment: There was `s.tk/denver`, but that's obsolete now so I won't bother adding it.

Comment: Do we really need ones for Jeff's and Joel's profiles?

Comment: @Cole I can't imagine anyone using them but it's not like there is a negative cost to having them there.

Comment: @Amicable No! You see, It's a conspiracy! They're slowly but surely implanting doctrines in our minds! It's subtle things like these that make it hard to pick up on! Don't you get it!? They are promoting themselves as the leaders! They're plotting to take over! We can't have that! You need to [be on the lookout](http://aaaaa42.tumblr.com/post/50860038031/mcporno-keep-your-eyes-peeled) to notice things like this!

Comment: First Stack Exchange and in 6 to 8 weeks, the world!

Comment: `s.tk/blender` is currently going to a private staff Google Hangout.

Comment: `s.tk/meta` should now point to Meta.SE, no?

Comment: Why is `/hyphen` how they choose to refer to Expert Exchange? Why not `/arch-nemesis` or `/anti-christ`, or `/arch-enemy` or `/rival`?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Because it's none of those things? SE won by a knockout. Today's rival would be Quora. (Also, "hyphen" refers to what happens if it's omitted from the domain name: expert**sexchange**.com)

Comment: @2mkgz: That's hilarious - I've never noticed that before.

Comment: @JeremyBanks the first, s.tk, no longer works.

Comment: @ike Yeah, they just changed to a new system without the wildcard behavior that s bunch of links rely on. I'll need to reverify everything.

Comment: @ike Updated the list. Several of the links are gone -- some seem pretty arbitrary. Heh. I guess these aren't to be relied on.

Comment: @JeremyBanks looks like s.tk is back.

Comment: @JeremyBanks How about http://[site].s.tk? How can I feature-request it?

Comment: @Pandya [There's a form here to suggest new links](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1p0Jw76_RhUoNZWA-vqLWCBtdss9gh18r0xtBJe6XFyw/viewform?formkey=dHZLQjdhWjdyRGRub21TTjNMOXo2Mnc6MQ), but I'm not sure that the submissions have *ever* been used. Realistically, you could try posting a feature-request here tagged with s.tk, but it's not likely to be implemented. Changes mainly seem to be made based on marketing needs.

Comment: @JeremyBanks [discussion](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5042058#5042058)

Comment: Was there a discussion somewhere explaining the "BudURL migration"?

Comment: @MarkHurd what is "BudURL"? Never heard that term.

Comment: BTW @JeremyBanks do you work for SE now? You're not listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/company/team)

Comment: Oh cool @JeremyBanks, didn't know you made the team. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard &Jeff: I do. :) I just started last week. I expect I'll be added eventually.

Comment: Congrats, that's good to hear! :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's the logo displayed if you try a shortcut that doesn't exist E.g. [DNE](http://s.tk/dne) or, at the moment, [SO](http://s.tk/so). The phrase I quoted is in the edit summary of Jeremy Banks from  Mar 14, 2016, at 22:36.

Comment: @MarkHurd I don't believe there was ever any discussion about that. I just observed the change when I was reviewing the list and saw that some had broken.

Comment: @JeremyBanks So can you find out why the main sites were dropped then? It doesn't affect me much with Chrome's automatic predictors getting it right with `st` (and normally just `s` when I've been working more than watching (V8) super cars), but `s.tk/so` is (was) a nice shortcut from unfamiliar browsers or computers.

Comment: @JeremyBanks could we have s.tk/alcohol to point to Beer, Wine, & Spirits?  s.tk/beer is already taken (by Homebrewing) and it's causing a little confusion; would be great if we could tell people a shortened URL to use for the other site.  Thanks.

Comment: I just used [the linked form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk/109802#comment911342_109802) to ask for a shortened URL for [spanish.se]. I hope it is still in use :)