# How do we get a new s.tk added?

Tags: support, s.tk, s.tk-request

What is the process to get a new `s.tk` shortened URL added to the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we're currently in testing for using S.TK, we're not rolling it out across the entire network as a general purpose shortener.  That means that there are no S.tk links automatically created (such as through the sharing tools) and instead, the need to all be created manually.

Right now, we're keeping it to general resources and the homepages for all of the SE sites.  [You can see a pretty good list of all the S.TK links here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

(2017 update) - We're no longer taking requests for additional links, or assigning them to beta / graduated sites. We do plan to use the domain internally as a reliable shortener for share links / etc, but have no ETA on when that will be rolled out.

Comment: I've requested for one short link; How will I responded/notified?

Comment: I think http://s.tk/linkrequest is not being maintained any more. Can we have any update or Should I make separate post or just ignore?

Answer (score 8):

Revisiting this in 2017 :)

We no longer support manual addition to the list of [s.tk](http://s.tk) URLs. This is for the following reason:

- We do plan to use the domain internally for things (e.g. sharing URLs) as Alex mentioned
- Adding new URLs to the domain is a manual process, as is testing existing links to ensure validity
- It's too difficult to make a very arbitrary criteria for 'worth a link' fair and easy to explain to everyone that requests one.

The domain was always intended to primarily shorten internal links so that we could eventually overcome the issues that third-party link shortener services present while still offering the convenience to users. Allowing for some easy shortcuts was a plus, but not the primary purpose, and it's that purpose we need to keep in mind.

We're not sure what we're going to do with existing links at this point (if you notice, we have not been assigning shortened links to new beta / graduated sites for quite some time), but we're definitely not going to be creating more. Sorry for any inconvenience or disappointment, but it's just not something we can continue to support.

Comment: What about requests that were done [so long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk/109802#comment958544_109802)?

Comment: I found that BudURL.co is now BL.INK ; is there any update?

Comment: Why was [**s.tk/so**](https://s.tk/so) taken down? (sometime between [2013 and 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171373/370758))