# Ability to create short URLs

Tags: discussion

Many people link to Stack Overflow questions. I think it would be quite handy to **have the option** to create short links from Stack Overflow Questions.

Example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565978/how-to-interpret-a-crashlog-with-no-references-to-a-specific-class/7648558#7648558
```

could be turned into

```
http://stackoverflow.com/s/4dkls2
```

maybe even something like

```
http://stack.of/s/4dkls2
```

Comment: Down with short URLs!

Comment: I don't say they are good in every case but I have come across cases where I am very glad to have short urls. F.eg. when sending a link via SMS or Twitter.

Comment: @Besi: Twitter makes them shorter automatically

Comment: Short URLs are a **Bad Thing**. Stack Overflow's policy should be to make the developer community aware of this, not to contribute to the problem.

Comment: (Those of us who do like short URLs aren't standing up for you because we've already been denied several times. :P)

Comment: One of those times was my suggestion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110407).  You'd also be interested to know that we have a URL shortener with some links at [s.tk/](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk).

Comment: I don't say you have to like short URLs I think it clearly depends on the usecase. But I stated that it would be good to have the option to create them...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is already implemented, your example question can be reached from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7565978
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was not aware of this.

Comment: I don't think this is a satisfied answer. I expect something like `http://stack.of/s/4dkls2`. Otherwise `stackoverflow.com`, we also have `meta.academia.stackexchange.com`. And I don't use Twitter.