# Is it possible to use the SE URL shortener for key meta posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, s.tk

There are several key meta posts that I often want to link to in comments:  Introductory posts, posts of settled debate about what our community is, etc.

Some of these are so common that I started using tinyurl - but then I discovered [Stack Exchange has a URL Shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk).

What I didn't see was a way to shorten key meta posts.  Does such a beast exist?  Could mods be allowed to nominate a site list of key meta posts (like the FAQ) if they don't?

Comment: Perhaps an extension of the magic links could allow arbitrary question linking; something like `[Meta:267966]`.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110407/please-add-question-and-answer-shortlinks-with-site-names-to-the-s-tk-url-shorte?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the URL shortener can only be used for a fixed and limited number of targets. It cannot be used for arbitrary posts.

You can use the `/q/<questionid>` route on a given site instead; the link to this post is:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237966
```

for example.