# Add hashtag with tag of question in 'share' before posting

Tags: feature-request, sharing, share-this

I have two suggestions by clicking 'Share' a question or answer:

- When click  in Twitter and Facebook auto add `#{main tag}` (`{main tag}` represents first tag in question) in field text, like this:

  <kbd>[image: twitter share]</kbd>
- Create short links in Twitter (I know it might be unfeasible, but it's just a suggestion) instead of the entire link, maybe using https://dev.twitter.com/overview/t.co

Comment: Might be worth a bump of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110407/270345

Comment: Downvote? I don't understand...

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @AlE. I understand the use of the votes, I don't understand is why disagrees of my suggestions.

Comment: I guess somebody thinks it's not a good idea. Someone else seems to think it is.

Comment: @AlE. thanks for explaining, but still do not understand, is not something that will dramatically change the site's features, it is just a "simple suggestion" with the intention to encourage and facilitate people to use social networks to promote the "SE communities" with the "`#hashtags` tracking". I'll really stop giving suggestions here. Thank you again! Goodbye.

Comment: Please do not try to force other networks onto the site. There are enough distractions already.

Comment: @Mast the tool exists on all the sites on the network, so it seems to me to be valid as something global. Outside this post is 4 years ago and since then I haven't opened any new "question" to **"SUPPOSEDLY distract people"**, I just edited something fast that doesn't interfere compared to the hundreds of editions that occur. So you don't have to overdo your appeal.

Comment: I'm simply replying to your comments, that almost make it seem natural for such a thing to exist, that it's a minor thing to add and that you can't understand why someone would disagree. No reason to get defensive about it.

Comment: @Mast It is not a matter of defensive, it is a question of why something so simple that it is a need that is obviously for people who use the **"share tool"** (and obviously it’s not everyone’s need, because not every world shares in social) and not for everyone to be a reason for disagreement. if the "disagreement" is with those who use "share tool" and have solid arguments about it then it makes sense, if the disagreement is something like "we have bigger problems", then it doesn't make sense, because one problem doesn't interfere with the other.

Comment: There is no *need* for this. Not at all.

Comment: @Mast you are handling the "stackoverflow.com" website issue, the tags help and I believe that on most sites it would be useful. The most you can assume with all of this is that your statement is more for opinion or even for isolated cases. Let's face it, if the person shares and there is a tag on the site, it is because whoever follows the subject of that site on a social network is because they already understand the usefulness of the tags. If your argument were reasonable, the "sharing tool" itself is not useful on other sites and perhaps not even in feeds (RSS).