# How about introducing <site>.s.tk work as <site>.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, s.tk-request

As we know that http://s.tk work as http://stackexchange.com. As listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109802/260388) we've many s.tk URLs for communities and beta-communities. I've visited [How do we get a new s.tk added?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109961/260388) and related [form](http://s.tk/linkrequest) for requesting new which deals with `The part of the URL after S.TK/` for `Desired slug`.

But my topic is How about introducing `http://[site].s.tk` work as `http://[site].stackexchange.com`? The **advantage** is we don't need to define for each communities and beta-communities separately!

So, I'm [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)ing for defining `http://[site].s.tk` that work as `http://[site].stackexchange.com`.

Comment: A link shortener for each community? That's another 150 domains to manage! Another domain to manage is not free.

Comment: @Oded isn't it free for big enough a company, aka company paying enough already for hosting?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - "free" is not just about buying the domains. It is also managing them - someone has to do that.

Comment: And that's before we even start talking about making HTTPS working with it, @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Oded isn't it just some server settings? Or host? afaik, the "main" domain can check for the sub domain, if exists, and serve proper content (i.e. it's just matter of coding). As for ssl you're right, but since it's just a URL shortener I don't think it's really required

Comment: Still - the effort in managing these is not nothing. And the shortener application would need to change to enable this scenario. You forget that there is an application (and database) behind these, @ShadowWizard - these are all resources that need to be provisioned and managed, as well as manpower to ensure they are running and working correctly.

Comment: In particular for something of little benefit. We have a very short link shortener URL. That's the point of it - adding a subdomain makes it longer and makes it less effective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of a link shortener (like s.tk) is to have *short links* - adding sub domains to it will just make links longer – it defeats the point.

There are costs associated with adding subdomains – not necessarily direct financial costs (if we own the domain and have DNS servers, adding more domains doesn't cost us more, vs having to register domains with a registrar) but other costs.

These include:

- DNS lookup – extra lookups for these subdomains on the DNS server
- Management costs – someone has to add these domains, then maintain them
- Certificate costs if we do want these to support HTTPS (these also need management)

All of the above for very little benefit – it isn't as if s.tk isn't doing its job.

Comment: How about using `s.tk/SITE/STUFF` rather than `SITE.s.tk/STUFF`? The redirection is systematic so the management costs are negligible, and there are no extra DNS lookup and certificate costs since it's all `s.tk`. Right now `s.tk/SITE` exists for some sites but not all (why?) and something like `s.tk/SITE/q/1` doesn't work.