# Provide a vanity shortened URL redirect for each SE site

Tags: feature-request, vanity-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

It's no big secret that SE sites won't be getting vanity URLs for newly-launched sites. However, the names of the sites are kind of difficult to advertise in meat-space, especially for non-technical sites such as [Travel-SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). As somebody on Travel noted, if you try to dictate the domain name, it goes like:

> travel dot stackexchange dot com

at which point you are glanced as if you are mentioning a contagious tropical disease, and a question pops:

> A whatexchange?

followed by a five-minute explanation how exactly it's written and spelt.

Stack Exchange sounds too geeky to, well, non-technical persons. It would be much better if I can give them a short URL that they can remember or write down quickly, which would simply redirect to the actual `se-site.stackexchange.com` domain name.

For example, for Travel-SE, it might go like

> travel.foo.bar

or

> foo.bar/travel

These won't be a substitute for the domain name -- again, they are handy to give out to other people, especially when not on the Internet.

Comment: It's too bad we can't afford one of those newfangled ICANN names, because `.SE` would make a lot of sense, as in `Travel.SE` Or, we could all just move to Sweden. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Oh, I've already done that. Waiting for you guys to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They already exist, using the s.tk domain name: http://s.tk/travel

See the complete list in [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk).