# Quick speed to the hilt of Stack Overflow with a shorter URL

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I just tried to reach `stackoverflow.com` by typing `www.so.com`, and that webpage is taken by a generic directory page. Does anyone else agree in the goodness if `www.so.com` was owned by Stack Exchange?

If this is out of the picture, what about URLs like `stckvrflw.com` (all vowels jettisoned) or maybe something like `llllV` (psedo-mnemonic URL).

Otherwise, is there any chance that stackoverflow.com can be reached quickly, other than typing out the whole URL (or tricks like bookmarks, etc.)? I often visit from the library and public machines.

Comment: Why the downvote? Honest question

Comment: +1 to counteract the negative press!

Comment: @ninesided - Much appreciated, btw I love your geometric monicker here. nonagon-fan?

Comment: I love me some nonagonal action :-)

Comment: @Adam Downvotes on Meta mean someone disagrees with your suggestion, not that its a bad post.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman thanks much my friend - I have tough skin now!

Comment: Adam, instead of editing your question to declare a "winner," it's much more useful if you just accept the answer.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - I am old-fashioned , I know. I will do as you prescribe however. Appreciation unto you

Comment: Isn't this what your browser's URL completion feature is for?

Comment: @dmckee - You are right, thanks !

Comment: @ninesided: It's not your job to "undo" someone else's right to vote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - true, and it is not _your_ job to police other people's voting habits. I thought it was a worthwhile question and I +1'd it, as is my right.

Comment: @ninesided: You are correct. And, if you upvoted it on its own merits then I do not disagree with that. However if, as you indicated, you did it "to counteract", then I _do_ disagree with that, which is my right also. Voting fraud is srs bizness yo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's an [official URL shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk) available through [s.tk](http://s.tk): [s.tk/so](http://s.tk/so) is probably as short as you can get without sacrificing a goat to the Old Gods.

Comment: Awesome, that is quite easy! thanks much man

Comment: still longer than `so.com` :)

Comment: So.com is totally useless and we should take it over - http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/so.com#

Answer (score 2):

SO should always be your home page, that way you don't need a book mark or to type a URL, just open your browser or click the "home" button!

Comment: This would be more humorous if he hadn't mentioned `I often visit from library and public machines.`

Comment: pfff... details. It takes five seconds to set up a home page on public machine. Unless they lock the home page.

Answer (score 0):

If you search **stack** in Google, a link appears on the first page (for google.com and google.com.au for me)...that's pretty short and most browsers have a search box or google front page...

Comment: Laziness in typing is a noble virtue.. I have carpal tunnel...