# s.tk not working anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, s.tk

The [SE link shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk) (http://s.tk) is no longer working.

Could this be fixed?

Comment: I'll ping someone about that. This isn't intentional. (Well, it being down *might* be intentional if we're doing some maintenance or something that I'm not aware of, but point being that it'll come back up ... sometime.)

Comment: @anna K, thanks :)  I was afraid they were killing it due to lack of use or something :s Also, could it be updated to include new beta sites? Last I checked, s.tk/chemistry lead me to SE.com/chemistry (whereas older beta sites work)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, there where two issues here.

1) Someone (who I will not name for the sake of all involved) ... may have not chkconfig on'd the named service when he/she/it rebuilt the NY DNS servers to upgrade them to CentOS 6.x

This caused two of our 4 DNS servers to not respond to any requests when they where rebooted for patches yesterday night. We should have been alerted to that, but it appears we weren't which I will have to look into.

2) At some point the s.tk config was removed from our slave config in mercurial. I will have to go through the file history to see who to properly blame for that.

At this point I have corrected both of these issues and all should be well in the world again.

Comment: I guess _it_ is for including cousin It. `;)`

Comment: It's down again, could this please be fixed? :)