# Is there a way to shorten Stack Overflow URLs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

There is a link to refer to a Stack Overflow question, but does SO provide a shortened URL?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/q/14405584` What is "SF" though?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Server Fault?

Comment: Funny I just noticed today Amazon has a short url.

Like http://amzn.com/B0028BDM72 It would be COOL if the share button on StackOverFlow sites could emit something like http://stkovrflw.com/q/2574

This makes is easy to consume these urls into mobile devices

Comment: Like Hyperlinking?

Answer (score 61):

You can remove the whole part after the question ID (in the case of this question, the `/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-the-stack-overflow-urls`).

### The longer, more manual way:

The formula for shortening a question is `sitename` + .com/q/ + `question id`

This question's full URL is `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164194/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-the-stack-overflow-urls`

The shortened version is `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164194`.

Similarly, you can do this with any other site in the SE network:

```
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/why-add-salt-to-the-water-when-cooking-pasta
```

becomes

```
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2574.
```

### The fewer-things-to-delete way:

Use the "share" link underneath any question or answer. The URL you see in the pop-up follows the formula above, but it appends your user ID to the end (so that you can get badges like [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer)). You can copy & paste the whole URL in the "share" box, or strip your user ID from the end. Either way, it's short.

[image]

Comment: And if you're not logged in the "share" link doesn't even have a user ID to delete.

Comment: I wanted to shorten my user page link and the same idea applies: `sitename/u/<user_id>` instead of the full `sitenames/user/<user_id>/username`

Answer (score 5):

Some StackExchange general and community pages can be reached by STK's own URL shortener, http://s.tk/. (see [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/))

For questions, however, this seems not to work.

Answer (score -7):

You could always use http://tinyurl.com/ if you want to shorten a URL for sharing.

If you want to name your url w/ Markdown you can always use brackets: [Linking in StackOverflow] (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)