# Expand the s.tk/{site} shortcut to include questions

Tags: feature-request, vanity-url, s.tk

Right now I can hit `s.tk/sqa` and be taken to the SQA Stack Exchange site. An awesome feature (documented in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)).

I can also go to `sqa.stackexchange.com/q/73` as a quick way access a question or answer id. This is useful for things like sharing on twitter.

Is there any possibility of combining the two? Something like `@myfriend hey, you used to fooble the flux capacitator - can you help this question? s.tk/sqa/q/73 Thanks buddy!`

And with a little luck, there'd be `s.tk/sqa/q/73/65` at the end so I get credit for the share.

Comment: That's too bad. I searched and couldn't find it. Must have used the wrong keywords. :-\