# One word, two sites... how to divide the beer?

Tags: discussion, s.tk

There is already this existing shortcut: http://s.tk/beer

As you can see, it (currently) redirects to https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

This is bit weird, since the site is not really about beer but rather the brewing process but guess now it's too late, the site exists for over three years and that shortcut probably used in many places.

The true problem is that now we have https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ out in the open which is all about... beer. So `http://s.tk/beer` is the most expected shortcut. So, which beer goes where? Will there be a different shortcut for the beer site, or will the existing shortcut be changed e.g. `http://s.tk/brewing`?

Comment: You made my thirsty...

Comment: @juergend your what? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard His thirsty. Like making his day, only it's his thirsty.

Comment: Maybe s.tk/beer and s.tk/booze (Joking)

Comment: Who owns `s.tk` (and why hasn't [se] bought it yet if not them) and why aren't we officially using it for all [se] sites? `s.tk/o` for [so]?

Comment: @Dukeling What makes you think Stack Exchange don't own it? [They do](http://www.instra.com/en/whois/whois-result/s_tk). It is used as shortcut to most sites, you can see full list [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

Answer (score 3):

The site formerly known as Beer is now Beer, Wine, & Spirits with the URL https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/.  So while it could still have a claim on the short-form "beer", it's a weaker claim (why not "wine" or "whisky" or something else?).  The conflict with the site URL is no longer present, and that was probably the biggest source of confusion.

Comment: Well, now I expect http://s.tk/alcohol or http://s.tk/wine to work... neither does at the moment. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, we need to get ourselves some alcoholic short links!

Comment: Not to be confused with alcoholic short*cuts*, which interestingly don't quite lead to the same place.