# Update s.tk/meta to point to MSE instead of MSO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mso-mse-split, short-links, s.tk

The Stack Exchange's [s.tk URL shortener](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk) is quite useful for getting to sites quickly.

However, http://s.tk/meta still points to [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com), which *used* to be the network-wide Meta. Now that we have [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com), shouldn't it point here?