# Is there any way to shorten links to comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I'm wondering if there's a way to use the http://s.tk/ link shortening format for links to comments or if there is another abbreviated way to link to comments.

Long story short I'm trying to link to several comments in a custom mod flag to show a pattern of behavior, but the comment links are rather long so they use up too many characters.

For example:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247308/is-there-any-way-to-shorten-links-to-comments#comment810485_247308
```

Related: [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

Comment: Example comment to link to...

Comment: Related (the first includes short forms): *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls/332251#332251)* and [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can omit the slug and abbreviate `/questions` to `/q`:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247308#comment810485_247308
As [suggested by Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247309), you can use the slightly shorter but less discoverable form
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/810485

And if the link is on the same site, you can omit the protocol and host, but that won't automatically recognized as a link, it has to be used in an explicit mini-markdown link — [example](/posts/comments/810485) (typed as
`[example](/posts/comments/810485)`, which is shorter than
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/810485`). The flag display renders mini-markdown.

Comment: Except for the last sentence, your post is almost identical to Tim's.

Comment: It would be really useful to have a mod confirm whether omitting the protocol and host works for flags.

Comment: @apaul34208 Confirmed.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can do `/posts/comments/<id>`, which is the format used by the inbox comment notifications. For example, a [link to your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/810485).

But that might not always be shorter than just dropping the slug from the URL and using the `/q/<id>#comment...` option. ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247308#comment810485_247308))

For the purposes of a flag, direct links to one or two initial samples might be sufficient (as I assume these are comments on separate posts), and then you can provide additional comment IDs that can be looked up manually if necessary.

Comment: +1 That's definitely an improvement. I'll leave this open for a couple days to see if any shorter methods pop up.