# Links to comments from review don't onebox

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, onebox

Last night, I tried copying a conversation from comments into chat, so it could be discussed there. However, the comments didn't onebox.

A little bit of [experimenting](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23164157#23164157) in the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) revealed that the timestamp gives different links for comments when in review.* While the link works (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247308/266359)), it [won't onebox in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23164158#23164158).

Is this a bug? ...it seems that either links to comments in the review pane should conform to the norm, but I think the real problem is in chat, since all links to comments should onebox.

---

* In my instance, where `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61682/if-a-non-religious-person-is-o‌​f-jewish-heritage-can-one-wear-the-star-of-david#comment168895_61682` is the regular link, `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61682/#comment168895_61682` is the link from review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url form you are using is less common, but indeed: valid - I'm updating chat to recognize that pattern. It should work shortly.