# Difference between [share-this], [permalink], [short-links]?

Tags: discussion, meta, permalink, share-this, short-links

This site (MSE) has three tags without a wiki page which look very similar: [share-this], [permalink], [short-links]. Do all of them refer to the "share" link / "share a link to this answer" dialog? If yes, should they be made synonyms and which name should prevail? If not, should they be documented in the tag wiki?

Sorry, it's bed time here and I can't read all the ~100 questions using those tags now. Probably someone knows without even looking?

Comment: I have a feeling if you post another question and I +1 it as well, my votes are going to be reversed towards you! :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, lol; in Italian we say "una ciliegia tira l'altra" (one cherry calls the next).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[share-this](/questions/tagged/share-this) is for any of the sharing options available on the site. That doesn't *just* include the permalink with your referrer ID on it, but also the Facebook, Google, and Twitter buttons that appear in that box, at the bottom of a question asking if you know someone that can answer, and possibly other places that I'm not familiar with.

[permalink](/questions/tagged/permalink) is specific to only the permanent link that is accessible to every single post on the site. It uses the post's ID and redirects the view, and is meant to be a URL that will always work and *never need to be changed* no matter how the question gets edited to change the title.

[short-links](/questions/tagged/short-links) is for the http://s.tk short links that provide shortcuts to various key pages of the network. It is not related to the sharing or permalink features in any way. See the FAQ: [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

---

I've updated all of their tag wikis with relevant information for each.

Comment: Great! I've fixed my mistagged question. :)