# Should [sharing] and [share-this] be merged/synonymized?

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

We currently have two tags on Meta Stack Exchange about sharing:

[sharing](/questions/tagged/sharing) (79 questions)

> For questions relating to sharing a post or promoting the site via email, on Facebook, or on Twitter.

[share-this](/questions/tagged/share-this) (55 questions)

> For questions about any of the sharing options available on the sites.

While an argument could be made that [sharing](/questions/tagged/sharing) is about the *process* of sharing a post, and [share-this](/questions/tagged/share-this) is about the *functionality*, this distinction is not always made in practice and I'm not sure it's useful either. Should the tags be merged/synonymized (making [sharing](/questions/tagged/sharing) the master tag)?

Comment: Since the feature and menu are both called 'share', shouldn't the tag be called `share`?

Comment: That would work for me, but there are many other tags here in gerund form, e.g. [voting], [posting], so [sharing] isn't really exceptional.

Comment: Semi-related meta about the [share-this] tag: [Difference between \[share-this\], \[permalink\], \[short-links\]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255858/difference-between-share-this-permalink-short-links) It does seem to further support that [sharing] and [share-this] are about basically the same topic.