# Can we try getting a short link for all our sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, short-links

Would look something like this

- Graphic Design = gd.s.tk
- Super User = su.s.tk

Let me know what you guys think about this. (All input is wanted)

Comment: Graphic design is http://s.tk/design. The list of all known ones is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795/323179), but not all sites are listed.

Comment: See the answer below for how to request new ones as paths. We're not going to implement short links as subdomains. That just adds way too much complication to the service that no one is interested in maintaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the right place to ask for those. According to [the community-maintained list of s.tk links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109802/266359), [`s.tk/linkrequest`](https://s.tk/linkrequest) is the place to request new s.tk links. Perhaps you should suggest this there.

---

[animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) (a Stack Exchange employee) endorsed this answer, simultaneously declining this feature request. He [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295770/can-we-try-getting-a-short-link-for-all-our-sites/295772#comment959628_295770):

> See the answer below for how to request new ones as paths. We're not
>   going to implement short links as subdomains. That just adds way too
>   much complication to the service that no one is interested in
>   maintaining.