# Change the behavior of the s.tk shortener to better admit our rate of expansion

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, short-links

> Related: [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)
>
> [Official shortened URL service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23834/official-shortened-url-service)

Currently, the `s.tk` shortener links to the corresponding site if you go to `s.tk/<site>`. If the site doesn't exist, it redirects to `stackexchange.com/<site>`.

This is fine, except the shortener only understands a limited subset of sites. For example, http://s.tk/physics works but http://s.tk/chemistry doesn't. http://s.tk/money works as well (but http://s.tk/mathematica doesn't), so this has nothing to do with beta sites. Currently, there's [a form one has to fill](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHZLQjdhWjdyRGRub21TTjNMOXo2Mnc6MQ&ndplr=1) to get a link shortener target.

I recall filling the form for Chemistry once (not entirely sure if I did this), the link still doesn't work. I find s.tk quite useful because it lets me quickly enter a site URL on mobile/etc.

It occurred to me that the rate of adding new sites is much more than the rate of adding new subpages to stackexchange.com. Could the behavior or the link be reversed? Currently, it looks up an in build list of links to subsites (and other special links) and redirects to `http://stackexchange.com/<something>` if the page isn't in the list. Instead of this, could the links to subpages and other "special" links (like `/faq`, `/jeff`, etc) be baked into the code and have it redirect to `<something>.stackexchange.com` if otherwise?

A cleaner way of doing this would be to allow `http://<site>.s.tk/` (even better: allow stuff *after* the slash in such URLs like http://.s.tk/faq)